# Calculating the angle of a linear regression line

Tags: go, statistics, linear-regression

I have some time series data and I am trying to calculate the angle of the linear regression line to work out if the data is trending up or down.

I have plugged my data into a library that gives me the slope (I couldn't find one that just gives me the angle) but am struggling to convert this to the angle.

The function i am using to get the slope is [this one](https://pkg.go.dev/gonum.org/v1/gonum@v0.7.0/stat?tab=doc#LinearRegression).

There are some related built in math functions such as `math.Atan()` but couldn't get them to give me the angle. Is there a built in math function for this or any third party libraries that can calculate it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

So `math.Atan()` is returning the slope of the Linear Regression line, but in radians. In order to get degrees you could do this:

```
_, slope := LinearRegression( ... )
deg := math.Atan(slope) * (180.0/math.Pi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the more correct way to say this is that `Math.Atan(slope)` gives you the ***angle*** in radians; you then need to convert it to degrees with a simple function like this:

```
public static double RadiansToDegrees(double radians)
{
  return radians * (180 / Math.PI);
}
```